# How do I constrain the parameter(s) of a functor using concepts?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I have the following concept:

```
template <typename T>
concept FunctorInt = requires(T a, int b) {
    a.operator()(b); //require the () operator with a single int parameter.
};
```

I use this in the following function:

```
template <FunctorInt functor_t>
void for_each_sat_lit(const int ClauseIndex, functor_t functor) {
    auto LitIndex = -1;
    uint32_t Count = h_SatisfiedLitCount[ClauseIndex];
    if constexpr (!satlit) { Count = h_LiteralsInClauseCount[ClauseIndex] - Count; }
    for (uint32_t dummy = 0; dummy < Count; dummy++) {
        LitIndex = NextSetBit(h_SATLiteralBits[ClauseIndex], LitIndex);
        functor(LitIndex); //LitIndex must be an int.
    }
}
```

This compiles. However, when I try and break the code by changing the concept to

```
template <typename T>
concept FunctorInt = requires(T a, float b) {
    a.operator()(b); //I intend to require the () operator with a single float parameter.
};
```

It still compiles, meaning it did not constrain the functor at all.

**How do I constrain a functor so that it can only have a single int parameter?**

MSVC: concepts.cpp

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
concept FunctorInt = requires(T a, int b) {
    a.operator()(b); //require the () operator with a single int parameter.
};

template <typename T>
concept FunctorFloat = requires(T a, float b) {
    a.operator()(b); //require the () operator with a single float parameter.
};


void Loop(FunctorInt auto functor) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        functor(i);
    }
}

void LoopShouldNotCompile(FunctorFloat auto functor) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        functor(i); //<< i is not a float.
    }
}

int main(const int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    Loop(                [](int   a){ printf("%i", a); });
    LoopShouldNotCompile([](float a){ printf("%f", a); });
}
```

If I change the definitions of `FunctorInt` and `FunctorFloat` using `std::invocable`, the same problem persists:

```
concept FunctorInt = std::invocable<int>;

concept FunctorFloat = std::invocable<float>;
```

Everything still compiles, whereas it should give a compile error on `LoopShouldNotCompile`.

**UPDATE:**

I settled on:

```
template <typename T>
concept FunctorInt = 
    requires() { [](void(T::*)(int) const){}(&T::operator()); }
 || requires() { [](void(T::*)(int)      ){}(&T::operator()); };
```

Which creates a functor that only allows a single `int` parameter and doesn't care about const-correctness.

Comment: No wait, I now see. You're getting the concept of Concepts all wrong. It doesn't limit the input allowed to a function. It just checks the parameter: if the function call syntax matches what is expected. You can always feed an `int` to a function expects `floats`. They implicitly get "promoted"

Comment: Yes, and I want to disallow floats!

Comment: I think you want to disable automatic promotion, i.e. `int` input to `float` function, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concept check if the type can be called with an `int`
but you cannot control promotion/conversion which happens before.

You can check signature of `T::operator()`, but then previous valid cases (as overload, template function, no exact function but similar (`const`, `volatile`, ...)) might no longer work.

For example:

```
template <typename T>
concept FunctorInt = requires() {
    [](void(T::*)(int) const){}(&T::operator());
};

void Loop(FunctorInt auto functor) { /**/ }

int main() {
    Loop([](int   a){ printf("%i", a); });
    Loop([](float a){ printf("%f", a); }); // Not compile
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jvn6vnn5E)

Comment: How is this different from what I said and what the OP already did?

Comment: OP has issue which might be at several points and not very clear what should really be forbidden. Should the functor be callable with an int or a float (you choose to create functor which allow only `float`) (OP's one and mine can be called(with promotion)), should the functor take `int` as parameter (so "fixed" signature) (my choice); Could we forbid promotion/convertion in concept (I don't think so).

Comment: A concept only matches the template argument. It doesn't matches when the function/functor is called. You cannot prevent/forbid float promotion. so I think it's not possible what the OP wants. Anyhow, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I solved the nailing down of the exact signature with a conjunctive concept.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to block a function from accepting any other type that you want, you can use a type matching function template... e.g.

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
requires std::same_as<T,float>
void func([[maybe_unused]]T f) {}

int main() {
    //func(1); // doesn't compile
    func(1.0f); // works
    //func(1.0); // NB: fails again, because float!=double
}
```

edit: shorter

```cpp
void func([[maybe_unused]]std::same_as<float> auto f) {}
```

Comment: That's helpful, but I want to limit the functor argument, not the int parameter itself.

Comment: @Johan I'm sorry. But in that case the question is not at all clear to me. The examples that you give do not make much sense. There is no reason why `LoopShouldNotCompile` should not compile, as the lambda with the float matches the `FunctorFloat` concept. Please clarify the question.

Comment: @Johan if you want to limit how an invocable can be used _inside_ of the function: that's not possible. There's no way to disable int-to-float promotion from the outside. And it wouldn't even be the use-case for concepts: that's not what they do.

Comment: With JHBonarius functor, you might create `template <typename F> requires(FunctorInt<F> && !FunctorFloat<T>)void Loop(F functor)`, but `[](int a){}` won't pass that constraint.